# pass byte array in webservice

Tags: iphone, ios

I have one webservice to which I want to pass one bytes array.
so how can i pass byte array in soap webservice.

How can I achieve this?
Hope you will give me the right solution.

Comment: Did you got the solution ? Can you please share ?